# Working code on Svelte REPL not working on Codesandbox

Tags: svelte, read-eval-print-loop, codesandbox

What makes the svelte REPL and other REPL's different? I tried to copy my working code on svelte REPL, both on my local computer and Codesandbox, but it's not working properly like on the svelte REPL.

TLDR: I test a simple scroll animation with svelte, gsap, and smooth-scrollbar.

Working Svelte REPL:
https://svelte.dev/repl/cb93047788684a31b51ec1f3b8846732?version=3.53.1

The same direct copy code on Codesandbox (I already add the dependencies,
but the scroll not working as in the Svelte REPL):
https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-voice-gquxh0?file=/App.svelte

In codesandbox shows a problem says: `Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

This really matters because the codesandbox replicates my real-life project environment. It's weird to write a working code and then can't implement it.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the zip file from the REPL and unzipping the file and running `npm install`? It used to be a post on the Svelte blog but for some reason it just links to the docs now, here's the [old article](https://web.archive.org/web/20220121073925/https://svelte.dev/blog/the-easiest-way-to-get-started) on the wayback machine.

Comment: And I would not expect CodeSandbox to work, but StackBlitz should, Svelte has a compile step, the REPL accounts for it, CodeSandbox does not.

Comment: @JHeth no, but I have found a workaround, rework the code without the smooth-scrollbar. It's all working in all environments.